# When does group cohomology commute with colimits of groups?

Tags: representation-theory, homological-algebra, group-cohomology

Let a discrete group $G$ be a directed union of subgroups $G_i$, and $M$ a $G$-module. Under what conditions is it true that $H^i(G,M)=\varprojlim_j H^i(G_j,M)$? One can write down a spectral sequence
$$ E_2^{p,q} = R^p\varprojlim_j H^q(G_j,M) \Rightarrow H^{p+q}(G,M), $$
so my question essentially boils down to when are the higher derived limit terms zero?

The specific examples I am interested in are $G=\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ as the directed union of its finitely-generated subgroups. In this case, does $R\varprojlim$ vanish for every $G$-module? Every $R[G]$-module finitely-generated over $R$, $R$ Noetherian?

Comment: I'm noticing if $G_j$ are finite, $M$ is an $R[G]$-module and Artin as an $R$-module, then $H^i(G_j;M)$ is Artin over $R$, being a subquotient of $M^{G_j}$, so $R\varprojlim$ vanishes by the Mittag-Leffler condition. However, I also hope for a result for Noetherian, non-Artin modules.

Comment: Here is a counterexample where the $R\varprojlim$-terms matter: one can show
$$ H^2(\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{Z}) = \hat{\mathbb{Z}} $$
(say: the bar construction shows $H_i(G,M)=\varinjlim H_i(G_j,M)$, now compute $H_*(\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{Z})$ and use the universal coefficient theorem), arising from $\varprojlim^1 H^1$ rather than $\varprojlim H^2$ (the latter is zero!) Also see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/365896/group-cohomology-of-q-z

Comment: The previous comment is incorrect, the correct statement is $H^2(\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{A}_f/\mathbb{Q}=\hat{\mathbb{Z}}/\mathbb{Z}$ (I'm not even sure how I reached the conclusion I did), but its point still stands